# ReactWrapper::setProps() error when attempting to set Redux props in component for Jest/Enzyme test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I'm writing a unit test for a **React** component that is connected to **Redux**. One of the functions is the component is that it displays data if `questionReducer.showquestions == true`. I have attempted to re-create this functionality in the component by setting props with `wrapper.setProps({ questionReducer: { showquestions: true } })`. However, when I attempt this approach, I get the error:

```
ReactWrapper::setProps() expects a function as its second argument
```

How can I properly set the props for the connected Reducer in the component I am testing?

Answer (score 1):

You should test the component alone, without being connected to Redux. That allows you to give props directly to component.

Example:

```
export class Component_ extends React.Component {
  // your component logic here
}

const mapStateToProps = {
  showQuestions: questionReducer.showquestions
}

const Component = connect(mapStateToProps)(Component_)
export default Component
```

And then in test you can just do this

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Component_ showQuestions={true} />
```